# Problem running Civilization 5 Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues, civilization-5

I have installed Civilization 5 from Steam and it was working fine, but when I tried to run it this morning it got stuck at the first step with the message `Preparing to launch Sid Meier's Civilization V`. What should I do?

Comment: Restart Steam and try again.

Comment: I did and it is still the same. I have tried to launch anther game and it ran with no problems. After that, I tried to launch Civ 5 again and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Did you try verifying the game cache?

Comment: To verify the game cache right click on the steam game and go to properties > Local files > Verify Integrity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening Task Manager and see if Civ's service (Launcher.exe) is already running in the background.

When I get this error with games, usually the above is the cause of the problem, and killing the process and starting the game again from Steam solves it.